# Calling an Oracle SP from ADO

Tags: oracle, delphi, ado

I'm trying to call a Stored Procedure with both in and out parameters from ADO

First a Little packagde and a SP :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE CD_package IS
   TYPE CD_cursor IS REF CURSOR;
   PROCEDURE CDList ( pCost IN Number, pList OUT CD_Cursor ) ;
END CD_package;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY CD_package AS
PROCEDURE CDList ( pCost IN Number, pList OUT CD_Cursor ) IS
-- returns a list of titles available at cost pCost
BEGIN
   OPEN pList FOR
    SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM DUAL;

END CDList;

END CD_package;
```

And my Delphi Code:

```
      With SP do
      begin
        Close;
        Connection := ADOConnection1;
  ProcedureName := 'CD_package.CDList';  
        Parameters.Clear;
        Parameters.CreateParameter('pCost', ftFloat, pdInput, 0, 2.2);
        Open;
        Last;
      end; // with
```

SP I a TADOStoredProc and ADOConnection1 is a valid connection to my OracleDatabase.

According to seval sites you should NOT create the OUT procedure. But here I end up in a catch 22.

If I omit the parameter I gent an error about missing paramater: [image]

If I add a Cursor parameter

```
...
    Parameters.CreateParameter('pList', ftCursor, pdOutput, -1, NULL);
...
```

I get an error that the parameters isn't declared correctly 
[image]

The obvious vould be swich away from ADO, but that is not possible since the program id filled with references to `_RecordSet`

So in short how do I call a SP in Oracle using ADO?

The only fixed things are Delphi and ADO. You are free to change the TADOStoredProc into an TADOCommand or query. As long as it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a "solution"  using ODAC:

By no means optimal. But since I can not get rid of the ADO driver this is my solution so far:

```
uses
  System.Win.ComObj;

type
  TCustomADODataSetHelper = class helper for TCustomADODataSet
  public
    procedure AssignFrom(Source: TMemDataSet);
  end;

  { TCustomADODataSetHelper }

procedure TCustomADODataSetHelper.AssignFrom(Source: TMemDataSet);
var
  RS: Variant;
  Stream: TStringStream;
begin
  Stream := TStringStream.Create;
  try
    Source.SaveToXML(Stream);
    Stream.Position := 0;
    RS := CreateOleObject('ADODB.Recordset');
    RS.Open(TStreamAdapter.Create(Stream) as IUnknown);
    Recordset := IUnknown(RS) as _Recordset;
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm8.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with OraStoredProc1 do
  begin
    StoredProcName := 'DDK.GetSystemSettings';;
    Params.CreateParam(ftString, 'APrefix', TParamType.ptInput).Value := '';
    Params.CreateParam(ftCursor, 'ASettings', TParamType.ptOutput);
    Open;
  end;

  ADOStoredProc1.AssignFrom(OraStoredProc1);
  DataSource1.Dataset := ADOStoredProc1;
end;
```